# Change the display value for a model field in Django

Tags: django

I have a simple model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    progress = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=4)
```

The progress field stores a percent value:

For example 52% will be stored as 0.52

My form looks like this:

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    progress = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

     class Meta:
         model = Person
         fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'progress']

    def clean_progress(self):
        return self.cleaned_data.get('progress')/100  # convert 52% to -> 0.52
```

My question is, how can I convert this value back in my UpdateView?
The form is prefilled with the values from the database. The value in the database is 0.52 but I want that the form is prefilled with 52.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add to your UpdateView `form_class` attribute:

```
class PersonUpdateView(UpdateView):
    ....
    form_class = PersonForm
    ....
```

And in `PersonForm` override `__init__` method:

```
 class PersonForm(ModelForm):
     progress = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

     class Meta:
         model = Person
         fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'progress']

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.instance.progress = int(self.instance.progress * 100)
         kwargs['instance'] = self.instance
         super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

     def clean_progress(self):
        return self.cleaned_data.get('progress')/100  # convert 52% to -> 0.52
```